# Segmentation fault while unpacking data from file ( using strtok() and strcpy() )?

Tags: c++, string, file-handling

Need help with this code I am writing for an school assignment.

Program takes student data from user and writes it into file named "Student Data". Writing in file works fine. Data is being written correctly.
But when data is being read from file I get a segmentation fault. I am trying to use strtok() to skip out unwanted characters.
After debugging I found out problem is with unpack function.Fault occurs at first line of  void unpack().

This is a very basic program. I really need to read data from file to do operations like search,update and delete.

Sorry if it is a very obvious mistake. I tried lot of things including searching for relevant questions. Nothing's working for me. I would really appreciate if you guys would take a look at it. Please help me out. Thanks.

Also please explain in simple terms where I am doing it wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int buffSize=250;

class StudentData
{
       char rollNo[12];
       char firstName[16];
       char secondName[16];
       char division[8];
       char address[32];
       char buffer[buffSize];

       //makes data more readable and copies it to buffer,buffer written as      it is into a file
       void pack()
       {
              strcpy(buffer,"| ");
              strcat(buffer,"ROLL NO: ");
              strcat(buffer,rollNo);
              strcat(buffer," ");

              strcat(buffer,"| ");
              strcat(buffer,"NAME: ");
              strcat(buffer,firstName);
              strcat(buffer," ");
              strcat(buffer,secondName);
              strcat(buffer," ");

              strcat(buffer,"| ");
              strcat(buffer,"DIVISION: ");
              strcat(buffer,division);
              strcat(buffer," ");

              strcat(buffer,"| ");
              strcat(buffer,"ADDRESS: ");
              strcat(buffer,address);
              strcat(buffer," ");

              strcat(buffer," |");
       }

       //data from file is available in buffer, copied into respective     variables for display
       void unpack()
       {
              strtok(buffer," ");
              strtok(NULL," ");
              strtok(NULL," ");
              strcpy(rollNo,strtok(NULL," |"));

              strtok(NULL," ");
              strtok(NULL," ");
              strcpy(firstName,strtok(NULL," "));
              strcpy(secondName,strtok(NULL," |"));

              strtok(NULL," ");
              strtok(NULL," ");
              strcpy(division,strtok(NULL," |"));

              strtok(NULL," ");
              strtok(NULL," ");
              strcpy(address,strtok(NULL," |"));
       }


   public:

       //add data to file
       void add_data()
       {
              cout<<"Enter Roll No: ";
              cin>>rollNo;

              cout<<endl;

              cout<<"Enter Name of student: ";
              cin>>firstName;
              cin>>secondName;

              cout<<endl;

              cout<<"Enter Division of student: ";
              cin>>division;

              cout<<endl;

              cout<<"Enter Address of student: ";
              cin>>address;

              cout<<endl;

              //pack data
              pack();

              //create ofstream object for writing in file
              ofstream outFile;

              //open in append mode
              outFile.open("Student Data",ios::app);
              //write contents of buffer to file and a new line
              outFile<<buffer<<endl;
              //close file
              outFile.close();

              cout<<"Data successfully added to file...!"<<endl;

       }


       void display()
       {
              cout<<"-------------------------------------------"<<endl;
              cout<<endl;
              cout<<"**********Student Information************"<<endl;
              cout<<"-------------------------------------------"<<endl;
              cout<<endl;

              cout<<setw(12)<<"Roll No";
              cout<<setw(30)<<"Name";
              cout<<setw(30)<<"Division";
              cout<<setw(30)<<"Address";
              cout<<endl;

              //create ifstream object to read from file
              ifstream inFile;
              //open file
              inFile.open("Student Data");

              while(!inFile.eof())
              {
                    //read data from file into buffer
                    inFile>>buffer;

                    if(inFile.fail())
                    {
                         cout<<"File failed to open"<<endl;
                         break;
                    }

                    unpack();

                    cout<<rollNo<<setw(12);
                    cout<<firstName<<setw(14);
                    cout<<secondName<<setw(1);
                    cout<<division<<setw(30);
                    cout<<address<<setw(30);

                }

                //close file
                inFile.close();

         }

   };


   int main()
   {
       StudentData s;
       s.add_data();
       s.display();

       return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` returns null pointer if no more tokens found, so you should always check the return value before utilizing it.

Another problem with your code is that you are using small buffer to read from std input, such as `cin>>rollNo;`, since write is not aware of buffer size it may overrun it and corrupt memory so you shoud use `std::string` or `istream::get` instead.

Comment: `strcpy(address,strtok(NULL," |"));` - will crash when `strtok` returns NULL.